# Where can I find a modul to add in a pivot view an interval "hour" (next to day, week, month, quarter or year)?

Tags: date, odoo, odoo-8

Where can I find a module to add in graph view an interval "hour" (next to day, week, month, quarter or year)?

I attach the image from Reporting/Point of Sale/Orders Analysis.

I check modules: sale_stock, sale, report, base, web, procurement, stock_account, stock and nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Correct your question is asking the feature is for Pivot view and not for the Graph View.[Also your attachment represents the Pivot View.]

You can check this app [Click Here](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/hour_for_pivot/)

Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I use odoo-8, and the app from the link is for v10. I`m trying to make it compatible for the v8 but it´s so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve found it, it`s in server\openerp\models.py

method name:

```
_read_group_process_groupby():
```